# Hiding ID at specific URL

Tags: jquery, url, hide, show

I'm having an issue getting this script to work.  I'm trying to hide the #merits ID on every page of our site except for our homepage http://wgzrv.ndxva.servertrust.com.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                var currentUrl = $(location).attr('href');
                if (currentUrl !== 'http://wgzrv.ndxva.servertrust.com') {
                $('#merits').hide();
                } else {
                $('#merits').show();
                }
            });
```

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with the script. Are you sure this is accessible in all pages though?

Comment: the homepage is the only page that loads homepage.css and it has its own style for merit which overrides the storefront.css definition. Why not just hide it with CSS in homepage.css?

Comment: @Radio, thanks for the simple solution I was just not seeing.  I did have to add {display:block;} for #merits in homepage.css, and {display:none;} in storefront.css worked.  Can you offer exactly how homepage.css is overriding storefront.css?  I see:

<div id="if_homepage"><link href="v/vspfiles/templates/USALight2015/css/homepage.css" rel="stylesheet"></div>

in the <head>, but where is this element being accessed?

Comment: imports.css is added to the head before homepage.css is added. Any styles in storefront.css that overlap will have its styles modified by homepage.css because of the load order.

Comment: Ok, I see.  But how does <div id="if_homepage"> work, or what is the logic that identifies the homepage url?

Comment: Sorry, @Radio.  I forgot to tag you about the question above.

Comment: Oh hey. I could not find a reference to a div with id if_homepage. Regardless, without knowing how your pages are served, I would guess that there is some servlet that builds the pages, and if its the homepage, adds the homepage.css file when appropriate.

Comment: @ToddWilliams if you can show me where the div is, I can take a look. Perhaps it's in the base definition in a content management system though?